# Append Output of Hostname Command to /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, bash, echo, hostname, hosts

I have a server in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk in which the hostname command outputs a hostname that is not a full domain and does not exist in the /etc/host file.

I'm working with some software that for some reason relies on the system hostname to work.

I wanted to append the output of the hostname command to the /etc/hosts file referring to the local machine.

Right now I have a host file that looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

I am running a command like this to append to the file.

```
hostname | tr '\n' ' ' >> /etc/hosts
```

The issue is that the hostname appends as a newline. Like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
ip-10-0-1-162
```

I want it to append to the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` to edit the first line of the file:

```
sed -i "1s/$/ $(hostname | tr '\n' ' ')/" /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
echo "`cat /etc/hosts` `hostname`"
```

You might be able to write that straight back to */etc/hosts* but I'd rather write it to a temporary file and then replace */etc/hosts* with that.

If you want no new line at the end of the file, use

```
echo -n
```

instead.

This assumes that you want to append to the last line in the file.

Comment: If I wanted a single line command to accomplish this method how would I do it?